# How to break into middle of Flow in MULE and return the message to client..?

Tags: java, mule, mule-flow

I have a Flow in MULE like below :

```
<flow name="MetaService">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/jcore/meta"  
transformer-refs="HttpParams" responseTransformer-refs="JavaObjectToJson">
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <component class = "com.java.Meta">
    <component class = "com.java.Meta2"

</flow>
```

This flow first enters my first component class : "***com.java.Meta***" . And whatever i "**return**" from this java class becomes the input for my second component class : "***com.java.Meta2***".

---

Now what i want to do is like :

I want to check for something in "**payload**" in class "**Meta**" and if it does not exist, then i want to return a *Java HashMap* to client (in form of JSON) containing the ***error*** key.

And if it exist, then i want to return the same "**payload**" to second component class "**Meta2**".

How can i achieve this..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your second component in a choice router, returning the current message its map payload contains the "error" key.

You can use a Groovy expression:

```
#[groovy:payload.containsKey('error')]
```

Comment: Actually the error (to be returned) is also a HashMap and the Payload is also a HashMap, so "payload-type expression" wont work..!!..ANy other suggestion..??

Comment: Changed my response accordingly.